# How do I get a Brother DCP-7065DN printer working?

Tags: scanner, brother

I had the scanner working in Ubuntu 12.04, but now when I try to launch `xsane`, I get a scanner not found error: `brsaneconfig4 -q | grep 7065` produces the following output:

```
144 "DCP-7065DN"
0 DCP-7065DN          "DCP-7065DN"        I:192.168.1.11
```

---

**Edit**: The problem was with setting a manual IP on the scanner. If I assign the IP address via DHCP, the scanner works!

Comment: I have the same scanner. Haven't had a chance to try it with 14.04 yet. I'll give it a whirl. Does the 192.168.1.11 match the configured IP of the scanner?

Comment: Yes, I set the IP address manually on the scanner.

Comment: Provided you can ping the IP the answer I provided has been tested and works under 14.04 32 -bit - haven't tried 64-bit yet, which version are you running?

Comment: same process tested working under 14.04 64-bit Ubuntu Studio

Comment: Did the answer below work as well for you as it did for me? If so, please up-vote the answer. Thanks

Comment: I personally have only been able to get this scanner working with a static IP, For what it's worth. Feel free to answer your own question so that your results may help others. Thank you!

Comment: I have the same scanner, but directly connected to the computer. Installs and prints correctly, but scanner is not seen by xsane or sane.

Comment: @user292734 What output do you get from `brsaneconfig4 -q | grep 7065` You may wish to open a new question referring to this one including that information. Ping me with a comment and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visit the page linked below:

[Printer Driver | Downloads | DCP-7065DN | United States | Brother - linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.1-1.gz](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=dcp7065dn_all)

Select Linux and .deb then click search

Download the Driver Install tool.

Open with file roller(aka archive manager) and extract to your home directory.

Open Files, Click on Home

right click on linux-brprinter-installer-2.1.1-1 go to properties, permissions and check the box allow executing as program or after opening the terminal as described below issue the command `chmod +x ./linux-brprinter-installer-2.1.1-1`

Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>

issue the commands:

```
sudo su

./linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.1-1
```

at Input Model Name enter
DCP-7065DN

You will be presented with:

```
You are going to install following packages.
   dcp7065dnlpr-2.1.0-1.i386.deb
   cupswrapperDCP7065DN-2.0.4-2.i386.deb
   brscan4-0.4.7-1.amd64.deb
   brscan-skey-0.2.4-1.amd64.deb
```

Agree to this.

You will then be asked to agree to their terms several times. Respond in the affirmative. After a short delay it will ask if you will specify the device URI specify yes – prompted with a number of choices I chose the IP option (12 or 10 in my case)

Enter IP address of printer. (You can set this via the front panel of the printer see note below)

Press Enter when prompted

Note:  The leading zeros **required on the printer** setup will break the sane configuration if you include them so strip them out. example (printer ip 192.168.015.024 = script input 192.168.15.24) otherwise you get this:

```
PING 192.168.015.024 (192.168.13.20) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.168.015.024 ping statistics ---
11 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 9999ms
```

If this happens to you, use brsaneconfig4 to fix it by removing the faulty configuration with

`brsaneconfig4 -r DCP7065DN`

and then re-adding it with for example (your IP will likely be different)

`brsaneconfig4 -a name=DCP7065DN model=DCP7065DN ip=192.168.15.24`

Note: I'm leaving the hyphen out of the model number, for some reason i had issues when I left them in.

Printing and scanning via SimpleScan or Xsane now functions

Tested on Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit and 64-bit as well as 16.04 64-bit and 18.04 64 bit.
Note: for 18.04 if you want to use xsane rather than Simple Scan you'll have to install it first with `sudo apt install xsane`

Comment: I have this printer and never knew this Q&A has been lurking around for four years :)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I only update answers when I realize somethings changed. I used this today on 18.04 so had to update it.

Answer (score 1):

[Brother DCP-7065DN, Ubuntu 14.04 64bit: Can print to network printer but cannot use the scan function](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486699/brother-dcp-7065dn-ubuntu-14-04-64bit-can-print-to-network-printer-but-cannot)

This is my more step by step version of getting this scanner going.