# Brother DCP-7065DN, Ubuntu 14.04 64bit: Can print to network printer but cannot use the scan function

Tags: networking, scanner, brother

I'm using brscan4 and can ping it using brsaneconfig4 and it finds it but i cannot scan from the computer using either simple scan or xsane image scanning. Both programs don't show the scanner as being present. Brother drivers downloaded and installed

```
dpkg -l | grep Brother

ii  brscan-skey                                                 0.2.4-1                                             amd64        Brother Linux scanner S-KEY tool
ii  brscan4                                                     0.4.2-1                                             amd64        Brother Scanner Driver
ii  cupswrapperdcp7065dn                                        2.0.4-2                                             i386         Brother DCP7065DN CUPS wrapper driver
ii  dcp7065dnlpr                                                2.1.0-1                                             i386         Brother DCP-7065DN LPR driver
ii  printer-driver-ptouch                                       1.3-8                                               amd64        printer driver Brother P-touch label printers
```

If i press the scan button on the machine it tells me to "Check Connection"
I've tried everything i can on the forums to no avail.
Any ideas?

SOLVED
the only thing that i can think of that I hadn't done was, in terminal created a scanner using brsaneconfig4:

`brsaneconfig4 -a name=DCP-7065DN model=DCP7065DN ip=192.168.1.201`
Get the IP Address by using the Menu button on the printer/scanner, select network, then TCP / IP, then IP Address.

I spent hours trawling the forums but the scanner started working when **I RESTARTED THE COMPUTER** and all was well. xsane picked it up and simple scan.

Still can't use the scan button on the machine but not worried about it.

Comment: Read this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2039840

Comment: Is the IP static or DHCP? : http://askubuntu.com/questions/456061/ubuntu-14-04-brother-dcp-7065dn

Comment: Static ip, and i'm an idiot.
I just restarted ubuntu and the scanner works fine over ethernet. xsane  picked it up after about 7 seconds.

Comment: @Tim it's definitely working over the network http://askubuntu.com/questions/456061/how-do-i-get-a-brother-dcp-7065dn-printer-working/456112

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Download and install drivers from the [Brother website](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=nz&lang=en&prod=dcp7065dn_all).

Select 'Driver Install Tool' download and install. This will install the lpr, CUPSwrapper and scanner drivers. Make sure you get the right ones for your operating system (i.e. 64-bit or 32-bit). I did this step over and over again and so I can't remember whether the package installed the right ones first time or not. The brother website has instructions for installing the drivers, make sure you follow them.

Open terminal and enter

> brsaneconfig4

This should come up with something like this

```
    USAGE: brsaneconfig4 [-OPTION]   OPTION:
   -a name=FRIENDLY-NAME model=MODEL-NAME ip=xx.xx.xx.xx    
   -a name=FRIENDLY-NAME model=MODEL-NAME nodename=BRN_xxxxx 
               : Add network scanner
   -r FRIENDLY-NAME [FRIENDLY-NAME ...]
               : Remove network scanner
   -q          : Query supported models and available network scanners
   -d          : Diagnosis
   -p          : Ping (for network scanners)  
   -s:[LABEL]  : Save current configuration
   -l:[LABEL]  : Load saved configuration
```

Find the IP address by plugging in and turning on the printer and then hitting the menu button until you get 'Network' press the down arrow button to select 'TCP/IP' then  'IP Address'. Alternatively you can do this by using brsaneconfig4

```
    brsaneconfig4 -p
```

Then you'll have to create your scanner for the scanner programs to see by entering this in terminal

```
    brsaneconfig4 name=put the name you want to call your printer here model=DCP7065DN ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

where x's are the numbers from the IP address you've just discovered. Then **RESTART YOUR COMPUTER!!**

```
    sudo reboot
```

To get the **scan button to work** you need to run the scan key (this bit is apparently 64bit or 32bit specific) so there may be some issues here if you don't have the right one.

```
    brscan-skey
```

then test if it sees your scanner

```
    brscan-skey -l
```

this should show you the name you just entered for the scanner.

Edit Apparently you need to run brscan-skey command once every session that you want to use the scan key. Open Startup Applications and enter

```
brscan-skey
```

as a command to get it to run automatically.

Apparently you need to have **gimp** installed to use the printer/scanner scan button. It is certainly the program that opens the scans on my computer.

You need to have installed sane-utils, but brother mention this in their instructions.

All done! 
Good luck!

p.s The printer stopped working over the network for only my ubuntu computers after an update. I found that it was not accepting full length ip addresses (that is 3digits.3digits.3digits.3digits). It started working again after I took out any zeroes at the start of any 3digit sequence, so .066 became .66 in the device url section of the printer properties under printers in the general settings e.g

```
socket://192.168.001.066
```

became

```
socket://192.168.1.66
```

Comment: Interesting, I've never even considered using leading zeros in an ip address... It seems superfluous to me, but that's just my humble opinion.

Comment: Superfluous yes, what is on the IP screen on the printer yes. So that is probably what most people would put in the IP address textbox when prompted to, unless they work with IP addresses and understand them better than me.

Comment: What do I put for the ip if my printer is connected by usb?

Comment: I would guess you don't need an IP address unless you are running the printer over the network, which you probably aren't if it is connected via USB.

Comment: > It started working again after I took out any zeroes at the start of any 3digit sequence

This is an often-made error. The leading 0 at the start of the address byte makes the parser software interpret this number as an OCTAL number, not as a decimal. So 066 (octal) = 54 (decimal), quite possibly not what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the upgrade modified the sane dll config file.

I discovered this:

`/etc/sane.d/dll.conf.dpkg-old`

... that contained the line

`brother3`

while `/etc/sane.d/dll.conf` just said

`brother`

After updating `dll.conf` scanning worked immediately.

I am on Ubuntu 14.04, using a Brother MFC-7440N network-attached (which uses a brscan3 driver).

Answer (score 1):

Thank You!  I had to tweak your solution a little but for others who may be having this problem here is what I did...
(And I apologize, I don't know how highlight the commands).

In terminal:

```
brsaneconfig4 -a name=BrotherMFC-J470DW model=MFC-J470DW ip=xxx.xxx.x.xx
```

(**Note : I removed the leading zeros in the IP**)

```
brscan-skey

brscan-skey -l
```

I also added the `brscan-skey` to the Application Startup as suggested.
Everything works like a charm!

Thanks again!
Jodie

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Please edit the original answer instead of posting a new one: that way it's easier for the next user to have all data in one spot.  Then delete this one.  Also, please review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... **;-)**

Comment: Alas, in my case brscan-skey -l did not find the scanner, which works correctly in every aspect other than the scan button.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and found out that in the file

```
/etc/opt/brother/scanner/brscan4/brsanenetdevice4.cfg
```

I had two lines with two scanner entries (one with the old IP address). I just removed the wrong line and the scanner started to work finally.

You can always list the scanners with `brsaneconfig4 -d`