# does Brother DCP-L2540DNR works well with ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, brother

Good day, can somebody please tell me if Brother DCP-L2540DNR works well with ubuntu.  Most of our computers which will be printing to this printer runs ubuntu 12.04, 32bit.  I just want to make sure that this printer will work well with ubuntu!  Thank you!

Comment: This one claims printing works, scanner needed some work: http://askubuntu.com/questions/486699/brother-dcp-7065dn-ubuntu-14-04-64bit-can-print-to-network-printer-but-cannot 12.04 will apply for this solution too/

Comment: We don't know for that specific model but the proprietary Brother printer and scanner drivers are well supported. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/636363/how-do-i-install-proprietary-drivers-for-my-brother-all-in-one-printer-scanner-f - I recommend installing drivers with the Brother "Driver Install Tool".