# how to setup simple scan on a local USB brother printer

Tags: usb, configuration, scanner, brother

There are similar questions out there, no answers yet. I have found;

https://askubuntu.com/questions/678454/brother-l2540d-setup-brscan4-for-usb-printer

[Brother DCP-7065DN, Ubuntu 14.04 64bit: Can print to network printer but cannot use the scan function](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486699/brother-dcp-7065dn-ubuntu-14-04-64bit-can-print-to-network-printer-but-cannot/)

I have a dcp-7060D - I have installed all the programs, it does print now. But it is a local USB printer.

I want to use Simple Scan or Sane.. The above gives help if you are doing it through a network and assign it an ip address.. but no help yet on how to get the applications or scan buttons working if its a local usb device.

Anyone?

Comment: scanimage does find the device, but this does not seem to help me use it.

james@james-550P5C-550P7C:~$ scanimage -L
device `brother4:bus6;dev1' is a Brother DCP-7060D USB scanner

Answer (score 0):

I had the same printer, and got it working.  A few items to check.

1. turn on verbose debugging for scanimage -L

```
export SANE_DEBUG_DLL=128; scanimage -L
```

This will give you more verbose output and show whether it found the driver and load it correctly.

2. check the file /etc/sane.d/dll.conf, and it needs the value brother4 inside it.

```
net
#abaton
#agfafocus
#apple
#bh
brother4
```

3. Add the file brother4.conf in the directory /etc/sane.d/brother4.conf. Contents below:

```
# USB-scanners supported by the brother4-backend
# Brother DCP-7060D 
usb 0x04f9 0x0249
```

4. Make sure you have the libsane-brother4.so. in the directory /usr/lib64/sane/ This is where the file reside.  You can get this file from the brother support website. Go to [Brother printer support website](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=ca&lang=en&prod=dcp7060d_all)  and download the scanner executable and look for the .so library files there.
5. Install xsane. It is a GUI frontend for sane.

[xsane info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ut26V.png)